# how to restart USB modem remotely?

Tags: batch-file, modem, usb-drive

I need, for some circumstances, to restart my USB modem (huawei e220) remotely, so is there any possibility to plug-in/plug-out my USB modem programmatically using batch script for example?
OS: Windows XP, Windows 7

Comment: kill process and then open

Comment: @getlost: Which process to kill ?!

Comment: Try to `telnet` into the modem's `IP address`.  if you get a `login prompt` then it should have commands to reboot the modem.  If so then they can be scripted.

Answer (score -1):

You could automate this with `devcon` from MS. Here's a link with good instructions on how to identify the ID to use. http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/1D120A90884C25AF862573A700602459